# Node.js: difference in file size when copying csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have the below code where I am reading from a CSV and writing to another CSV. I will be transforming some data before writing to another file, but as a test, I ran the code and see that there are slight differences between source and destination files without event changing anything about the files.

```
  for(const m of metadata) {
      tempm = m;
      fname = path;
      const pipelineAsync = promisify(pipeline);
      if(m.path) {
        await pipelineAsync(
          fs.createReadStream(m.path),
          csv.parse({delimiter: '\t', columns: true}),
          csv.transform((input) => {
            return Object.assign({}, input);
          }),
          csv.stringify({header: true, delimiter: '\t'}),
          fs.createWriteStream(fname, {encoding: 'utf16le'})
        )
        let nstats = fs.statSync(fname);
        tempm['transformedPath'] = fname;
        tempm['transformed'] = true;
        tempm['t_size_bytes'] = nstats.size;
      }
  }
```

I see that for example,

```
file a: the source file size is `895631` while after copying destination file size is `898545`
file b: the source file size is `51388` while after copying destination file size is `52161`
file c: the source file size is `13666` while after copying destination file size is `13587`
```

But when i do not use tranform, the sizes match, for example this code produces excatly same file sizes on both source and dest

```
  for(const m of metadata) {
      tempm = m;
      fname = path;
      const pipelineAsync = promisify(pipeline);
      if(m.path) {
        await pipelineAsync(
          fs.createReadStream(m.path),
          /*csv.parse({delimiter: '\t', columns: true}),
          csv.transform((input) => {
            return Object.assign({}, input);
          }),
          csv.stringify({header: true, delimiter: '\t'}),*/
          fs.createWriteStream(fname, {encoding: 'utf16le'})
        )
        let nstats = fs.statSync(fname);
        tempm['transformedPath'] = fname;
        tempm['transformed'] = true;
        tempm['t_size_bytes'] = nstats.size;
      }
  }
```

Can any one please help in identifying what options i need to pass to csv transformation, so that the copy happens correctly.

I am doing this test to ensure, i am not losing out any data in large files.

Thanks.

Update 1: I have also checked that the encoding on both the files is same.

Update 2: I notice that the the source file has `CRLF` and destination file has `LF`. Is there a way i can keep the same using node.js or is it something `OS` dependent.

**Update 3:** Looks like the issue is `EOL`, I see the source file has `CRLF` while the destination file / transformed file has `LF`. I need to now find a way to specify this my above code so that the `EOL` is consistent

Comment: Try to just open source and result file with hex editor and just check the differences. I think it is probably just encoding headers.

Comment: @Amadare42, thanks for your reply, i checked the files in a hex editor, they seem to be a lot different, altoght when i check the content its same. not sure what could be wrong

Comment: Well, if their contents are the same, but in file there are a lot of small differences, it is almost certainly just encoding difference. To check that you can specify encoding explicitly in your csv-reading framework of choice.

Comment: @Amadare42, i have checked the encodings are same but still there is a size difference

Comment: _“i checked the files in a hex editor, they seem to be a lot different”_ - details? _“i have checked the encodings are same”_ - how exactly did you do that?

Comment: @CBroe, initially, my code did not have encoding option set when using `fs.createWriteStream(fname, {encoding: 'utf16le'})`, after setting this i see that both source and dest stream have `defaultEncoding` same and i had checked the hex files before this change when i noticed changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup you EOL config:

```js
const { pipeline } = require('stream')
const { promisify } = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('csv')
const os = require('os')


;(async function () {
  const pipelineAsync = promisify(pipeline)
  await pipelineAsync(
    fs.createReadStream('out'),
    csv.parse({ delimiter: ',', columns: true }),
    csv.transform((input) => {
      return Object.assign({}, input)
    }),
    // Here the trick:
    csv.stringify({ eol: true, record_delimiter: os.EOL, header: true, delimiter: '\t' }),
    fs.createWriteStream('out2', { encoding: 'utf16le' })
  )
})()
```

You can use `\r\n` as well or whatever you need `$-new-line\n`

This setup can be spotted reading the [source code](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv-stringify/blob/master/lib/index.js#L234).

Answer (score 2):

The two main source of this kind of difference are:

1. EOL style (unix or ms-dos)
2. file encoding

Using the simple unix `file` command line utility you can check both the encoding and EOL style for source files. Make sure to use same options for dest files and any difference should disappear.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can i check EOL style, can you please share some example as to how i can check it

Comment: As I said @opensource-developer , using the unix `file` command line utility. Simply issue the command `$ file <filename>` and you have details about file encoding, if in the output there are no details about EOL, it means it is a unix style EOL file, if it shows something like `with CRLF line ending` it means it is a ms-dos EOL file.

Comment: the EOL descriptors are the same and also encoding, but still i see difference in size

Comment: So @opensource-developer you need to share some hex snippets with diff we can check.

Comment: Hi, sorry i checked the EOL now again and had made a mistake in checking earlier. My source file seems to have CRLF and destination file has `LF`. I have updated my question, is there a way i can keep the same EOL using node.js or is it something OS dependent?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eol could help you @opensource-developer

Comment: thanks, i am using the npm module `csv` as indicated in my code above, trying to see how i can integrate the eol with it, i think i need to somehow change the EOL after / during the stringify process

Comment: `record_delimiter` option of `cvs-stringify` seems to be what you are looking for, @opensource-developer

Comment: tried it but thats an option when parsing it, i think i need to set the EOL during write. Is it something OS specific, or can i set CRLF on a mac / linux machine?

Comment: Are you sure `record_delimiter` in `cvs-stringify` is for parsing? See description in https://csv.js.org/stringify/options/ (https://csv.js.org/parse/options/ has its own option of the same name).